# Ruby on rails failed push heroku-22

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a problem concerning the push on heroku, I changed the version of heroku from heroku-18 to heroku-22 and since I can't do the push on heroku I have the following problem:

```
remote: !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote: ! ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: ! and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: ! rake aborted!
remote: !     ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block
```

I don't know what to do can you help me ?

`bundle install` and `bundle update` have not changed anything and even removing `gemfile.lock` and doing bundle install does not work

Comment: Have you tried to run `bundle exec rake -P` as indicated in the error message? Also, check that you are using the same ruby version as used on heroku-22 (where the default has changed from heroku-18). It's likely one of your rake task definitions is wrong.

Comment: I did the command and here is the result: rake aborted!
ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block

Comment: Well, then run it again with `--trace` appended and check the stack trace of the exception. It will likely include the code location which causes this issue.